data insertion with Node.js in Postgresql avoiding duplicates
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
const {Client} = require('pg');
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

app.storageBlob('storageBlobTrigger', {
    path: 'attachments/{name}',
    connection: 'MyStorageConnectionString',
    handler: async (blob,context) => {
        const connection = new Client( 
            {
                host: "++++++",
                user: "+++++",
                password: "++++",
                database: "++",
                port: 5432,
                ssl:{
                    rejectUnauthorized: false
                }
            });
            try{
                await connection.connect();
    
                context.log(`Storage blob function processed blob "${context.triggerMetadata.name}" with size ${blob.length} bytes`);
                console.log("excel data: ",blob)
    
                const workbook = XLSX.read(blob, { type: 'buffer' });
                const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
                const sheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
    
                const range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(sheet['!ref']);
                range.s.r = 1; 
                sheet['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(range);
    
                const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet, { raw: false })
                console.log(data);


                for (let row of data) {
                    await connection.query(`
                    INSERT INTO stock2.stock (
                        project_prefix,
                        material_code,
                        producer_item_code,
                        description,
                        serial_numbers,
                        total_stock,
                        unit,
                        warehouse
                    ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8)`,
                    [
                    row['Project Prefix'],
                    row['Material Code'], 
                    row['Producer Item Code'],
                    row['Description'],
                    row['Serial Numbers'],
                    row['Total Stock'],
                    row['Unit'],
                    row['Warehouse']
                ]);
                }
                const result = await connection.query('Select * stock2.stock')
    
                console.log("Result: ",result.rows);
    
            }
            catch(error){
                console.log("Error: ",error);
            }
            finally{
                connection.end()
            }   
        }
    });    

I am reading Data from daily updated excel files. I need to update tables accordingly in my database. The Code adds the rows every time an update occurs but the problem is that I have infinity rows at the end, because the excel files have around 10000 rows. I did some research and came to an End to use the MERGE or INSERT.... ON CONFLICT but I'm unsure if that's the best solution. Can someone please help with the code?

Yes, you can use MERGE statement to insert data into Azure Postgresql DB by avoiding duplicates. Below is the sample example to insert data into Azure Postgresql db from a source to target table. In below source is employees table and the target is newEmployees table.
Data stored in source employees table:
postgres=> SELECT * FROM Employees;

Output:
id |        email        |     name      
----+---------------------+---------------
  1 | john@example.com    | John Doe
  2 | alice@example.com   | Alice Smith
  3 | bob@example.com     | Bob Johnson
  4 | john@example.com    | John Smith
  5 | charlie@example.com | Charlie Brown
  6 | alice@example.com   | Alice Cooper
(6 rows)

As you can see in the above table, data has duplicate values in email column. Below query uses MERGE statement with DISTINCT ON (email) to avoid duplicates. It selects distinct email and name pairs from the employees table, ensuring that only one row is selected for each unique email value and inserts new rows into the newEmployees table for email values that do not already exist in the table.
MERGE INTO newEmployees AS n
USING (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (email) email, name
    FROM employees
    ORDER BY email
) AS e
ON n.email = e.email
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (email, name)
    VALUES (e.email, e.name);

postgres=> SELECT * FROM newEmployees;

Output:
postgres=> SELECT * FROM newEmployees;
 id |        email        |     name      
----+---------------------+---------------
  1 | bob@example.com     | Bob Johnson
  2 | alice@example.com   | Alice Smith
  3 | charlie@example.com | Charlie Brown
  4 | john@example.com    | John Doe
(4 rows)

